# Trying to display 3 items on every row

Tags: css, width

I'm working on my website here: http://ecoshopr.com/ and instead of having 4 products for each row I would like to display only 3. This can be done by changing:

```
.product_item {
width: 25%;
}
```

to

```
.product_item {
width: 33.333333333%;
}
```

However, when I make that change something weird happens where it only display 3 products on every **other** row. The even rows only display 1 product for some reason.

Any advice on what I can do to get each row displaying 3 products?

Thanks!

Comment: can you create fiddle? this code you show is not enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try **Flexbox** https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/352/

```css
ul.products {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  list-style-type: none;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex: 33.33%;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="products">
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem laborum cupiditate, fugit beatae commodi, nemo velit, ipsa odit amet dolorum in iusto aut quia officia reprehenderit temporibus necessitatibus ullam id.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quod cumque, fugit non! Labore et ad voluptatum repudiandae dicta nobis odit. Repellendus magnam ex, alias autem quasi iure enim labore earum.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt harum nihil, odit repudiandae, mollitia vitae laboriosam doloribus fuga ea pariatur magnam consequatur, porro non nostrum inventore suscipit illo ullam ut!</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis possimus ipsa autem voluptatibus. Voluptatibus vero veritatis, officiis sit, dignissimos optio porro omnis tempora, id libero officia. Exercitationem blanditiis nihil, sint.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio perferendis, error suscipit eos impedit corrupti reiciendis officiis itaque id, et, maxime dolores quas veniam natus autem. Dolorem iure sunt, assumenda?</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore illum, repellat, pariatur ea quae, consectetur, sunt molestias ex assumenda totam harum fugit. Excepturi ducimus obcaecati nobis ipsam consequuntur tenetur. Delectus.</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the `width: 33.333333333%;` and remove this from your code:

```
.product_item:nth-child(4n+1) {
    clear: both;
}
```